# Sentences in first order logic for graphs

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic

I am trying to write first-order sentences about graphs.  We can use relation $E(x,y)$ which means that there exist directed edge $x\to y$. Moreover, we can use only $3$ variables, but we can arbitraly requantify each of them.

I show my trial, but I am not sure about corectness of them. Moreover, I can't write formula for particular cases.

(1) Graph is finite directed cycle.
$\left(\forall_x\forall_y E(x,y)\to\neg E(y,x)\right)\wedge (\forall_x\forall_y\forall_z E(x,y) \wedge E(x,z)\to y=z)\wedge (\forall_x\exists_y E(x,y)) $. Of course it should be ok only for cycles with at least $3$ edges.
(2) Graph is directed cycle with exactly $3n$ edges.
I think that length of this formula depends on $n$. So, first of all as above - conditions for directed cycle.  However, I don't know how to force exactly $3n$ edges.

Can you check my answers and help me with my wrong/empty reasoning ?

Comment: Conventionally, $\forall,\exists$ bind tighter than boolean connectives, so you should write "$\forall x\ ( \cdots \to \cdots ) \land \cdots$" rather than "$( \forall x\ \cdots \to \cdots ) \land \cdots$". But never mind your choice of brackets made the intent obvious anyway.

Comment: Can you explain more details ? I have a problem with these things

Comment: Are recursive definitions allowed?

Comment: Only first-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the negative answer to the question, as explained in my other answer, it is natural to ask some related questions, namely whether there is a set $S$ of axioms (in the same language of graphs) that are satisfied by:

> Only graphs that are either a cycle or an infinite chain.

Intuitively there is a global constraint that there is only one cycle/chain. Thus it is no surprise that the same kind of compactness argument works, by adding two new constants $v,w$ and adding for each natural $k$ an axiom stating that "$v,w$ are not reachable in either direction within $k$ edges". Each finite subset of the (modified) set of axioms is satisfied by an infinite chain together with an appropriate interpretation of $v,w$. Thus by compactness the axioms still have a model. But neither a cycle nor an infinite chain satisfies all the added axioms; contradiction.

> Only graphs that are a disjoint union of semi-infinite chains.

Again, intuitively the global constraint is that each chain is infinite (rather than being cyclic). The compactness argument is slightly harder to see here. Let $c_i$ be a new constant for each natural $i$, and then add an axiom for each $k$ stating that "$c_k \to c_{k-1} \to \cdots \to c_1 \to c_0$" (where the arrows indicate directed edges). Check that the same argument goes through.

> Only graphs that are a disjoint union of infinitely many (doubly-)infinite chains.

I'll leave this as an exercise. Note that the language only has the edge relation $E$, so if you think it can be axiomatized you must do so without adding any predicate-symbols or function-symbols (or constants). If you think it can't, prove it.

Comment: Note also that allowing the set of axioms to be infinite makes it possible that two classes of structures $C,D$ can each be axiomatized using the same language and yet $C \smallsetminus D$ cannot be axiomatized in that language.

Comment: For first sentence: interpretation of $v,w$ is about assigning some (arbitrar) nodes in graph such that $S\cup \{\phi_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is satisfied. Yeah ?  ($\phi_i$ denotes additional sentences about reachability)

Comment: @HaskellFun: Yep, and that assignment is always possible with an infinite chain. Note that it is crucial to add those two constants so that they must be assigned fixed vertices after all the new axioms are added. This is the strange non-constructive nature of the compactness theorem. More precisely, if we merely require $S$ to be satisfied by every infinite chain, then no single infinite chain with $v,w$ fixed satisfies all finite subsets of all added axioms $T$, and yet there is a model satisfying $S \cup T$ simply because there is some choice of $v,w$ to satisfy each finite subset!

Comment: Thanks for you help bro, to be short: we do assignment **after** choosing subset of set of formulas.

Comment: @HaskellFun: Right. That's all that the compactness theorem needs to be applied, namely from "for every finite subset there is some model" you get "there is some model for the whole set".

Comment: It seems to me that constans are importan. Lets suppose that $v,w$ are variables existentially quantified. Then, we don't managed to conclude contradiction. Hmm ?

Comment: @HaskellFun: Exactly right; which is why I said adding those constants are crucial. It's excellent that you are investigating the details of the argument, as it will give you a feel for how it really works. =)

Comment: @ user21820, could you help in two threads, please ?   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039109/finitely-generated-monoids-how-to-show-that-there-is-not-first-order-set-axiom?noredirect=1#comment4185814_2039109      http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041592/show-non-definability-of-biparted-graphs-graphs-with-eulerian-cycle-even-numb        http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041518/show-non-axiomitization-and-non-definability-n-folded-function

Comment: When it comes to your exercise I will try to solve it and I will give you a sign!

Comment: @HaskellFun: In my answer I explained why certain classes of objects are not axiomatizable. That applies quite directly to your first and third links, so you should follow the outline in your attempt. I will answer your second link there. As for my exercises above, to avoid cluttering the comments come to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic and ping me and I'll respond when I'm online.

Comment: For the second case: Is it crucial to use directed graphs?

Comment: @HaskellFun: It is not crucial; even for undirected graphs it is not axiomatizable, but the argument must be modified; have a constant $c_k$ for each integer $k$, and the axiom added for each $k$ must say "$c_{-k} \to c_{-(k-1)} \to \cdots \to c_0 \to \cdots \to c_{k-1} \to c_k$". The reason is that we want to force the final structure to have a vertex $c_0$ from which you can extend indefinitely in both directions. That is impossible if it lies in a semi-infinite chain.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Now, I focus on third problem. It seems that it has a chacne for be axiomatizable :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Finite directed cycle

Your attempt is wrong. In short, your attempt is "$\forall x,y\ ( E(x,y) \to \neg E(y,x) ) \land \forall x\ \exists! y\ ( E(x,y) )$", which asserts "for every (directed) edge there is no backward edge, and for every vertex there is a unique outgoing edge". The second part does force the graph to have an infinite chain, because it ensures that you can keep stepping to the (unique) next vertex. But nothing forces that chain to loop back on itself.

Have you considered that it is impossible? If not, you may want to think about it before looking below.

### Finite X

In general, even if one uses infinitely many sentences, one cannot force the structure to be finite if one must accept arbitrarily large instances and there is no global constraint, roughly speaking. In the case of graphs, all you can express are local constraints, namely the edges. So if there is a set $S$ of axioms that are satisfied by only cycles of all finite sizes, then you can construct a separate set $T$ of sentences, one for each natural $k$ that asserts "there is a chain with at least $k$ distinct vertices". Then there is a structure that satisfies any finite subset of $S \cup T$ (prove it yourself), and hence by compactness there is a structure that satisfies $S \cup T$. But any such structure must be a finite cycle (by definition of $S$) and hence cannot satisfy $T$; contradiction. Therefore such $S$ does not exist.

Comment: What about situation when $\phi$ may depend on $n$ ?  ($n$ is length of cycle).  I mean, maybe it is possible to get formula $\phi_n$

Comment: @HaskellFun: If you want to force the graph to be a cycle of fixed length, of course you can; just say that there are exactly $n$ vertices and say that every vertex has a unique predecessor and unique successor.

Comment: Is it sufficient to add to my formula constraints on fixed length ?

Comment: @HaskellFun: I do not understand your question. Do you know first-order logic and the compactness theorem?

Comment: Yes, I know these things. So, I was able to understand your answer. Simply, I would like to clearify evertyhing

Comment: @HaskellFun: Okay I guess I misread your comment. It is not enough to add to your formula, because you didn't specify unique predecessor. It turns out that you only need to specify existence of predecessor, since finiteness means that going backwards along the edges will eventually loop, but unique successor means that there is only one loop.

Comment: @HaskellFun: In fact, in general any finite structure of size $n$ is axiomatizable, because you simply use $n$ existentially quantified variables outside and then a formula saying that those $n$ objects are distinct and there are no others, and then specify all the predicates and functions value by value, which is possible since there are only finitely many values.

Comment: I think that this thread is for you :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000431/directed-cycles-logic-first-order-sentence-with-three-variables-proof-of-exi/2000744#2000744      I ask for help, there we may use only $3$ variables!

Comment: @HaskellFun: Note that the linked question is not the same as this one, but as you can see the generic method will use $n$ variables. I'll have to think about your other question as to whether $3$ is enough. Is variable shadowing allowed? It sounds wrong. How can you even do it for a 9-cycle?

Comment: Only information is: $variables may be arbitrary requantified$  - I think that may be shadowed

Comment: @HaskellFun: Well since $C$ is given to be a finite cycle we can in fact force the 9-cycle by saying "there is no $z$ such that either $x \to z \to y$ or $y \to z \to x$" repeated for for all three pairs, and also saying that $x,y,z$ are distinct and not adjacent. But then I don't see how to force a 12-cycle without more variables. I'd be surprised if someone finds a way.