# Finitely generated monoids - how to show that there is not first order set axiomatizing them.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, monoid

> Let $\mathbb{M}=\langle M,\circ, e\rangle$ be a monoid. We say that
>   $\mathbb{M}$ is finitely generated when there exist finitely many
>   elements in $M$ such that each element of $M$ may be generated using
>   only these elements.
>
> For example, $\langle A^*, \cdot, \epsilon\rangle$ is finitely
>   generated if only and only alphabet $A$ is finite.
>   Show that the class of finitely generated monoids is not axiomatized.

I would like to use Ehrenfeucht-Fraissé games to prove it.  I solved some tasks about showing not-axiomatization with these games, however mentioned exercises were about graphs.  So my solutions are based on relations (edges, degrees..). Here, I have no idea which side of this exercise should be attacked by me.

Help me please.

**Edit after hints of @Noah**
Lets suppose that such $\Delta$ exists. Then, lets extend signature by constans: $c_1,c_2,...$ and let $\Delta'=\Delta\cup \Gamma$, where $\Gamma=\{\forall_{x\in A}\forall_{y\in A}x\circ y \neq c_i:i\in\mathbb{N} \}$.  Of course we have infinitely many elements not generated by rest of elements. Using compactness theorem we conclude contradiction. Let $\Delta_0\subseteq\Delta'$ will be finite set. Then it is easy to see that it is satisfable - We can add properly many elements to $A$ generated by nothing and assign to them finitely number of constanst $c_i$.

What do you think about this solution ? If I am wrong, tell me where.

Comment: You've been asking a lot of questions about model theory, but I've noticed you're not using the model-theory tag. It's possible that adding this tag might get your questions a bit more attention.

Comment: You should require $x$ and $y$ to not be the identity (since otherwise your $\Gamma$ is not satisfiable), and your $\Gamma$ should also include sentences saying $c_i\neq c_j$ if $i\neq j$.

Comment: @EricWofsey besied of this is it ok >?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT THE LAST: Haha, wow, we missed the easy solution**.

Two hints:

- What can you say about the cardinality of a finitely generated structure in a language of size $\kappa$? *HINT: elements of the structure correspond to "words" on a certain set of symbols . . .*
- Assuming that there are arbitrarily large finite structures of the type you care about (that is, arbitrarily large finite monoids - which there are), how does that contradict the Compactness Theorem? *HINT: think about adding lots of constants . . .*

---

EDIT: This problem is a bit trickier than I thought at first, and my advice was somewhat misleading. There are several ways to solve it; let me outline some below, but first let me comment on your proposed solution. Your $\Gamma$ is in fact inconsistent: for *every* element $c$ there must be some $x, y$ such that $xy=c$.

Here are the solutions I see:

- *Compactness*. The fastest way is to use the compactness theorem, but the usage is a bit more complicated than what I had in mind. A *short monoid* (that's not standard notation) is a monoid with an identity $e$, an annihilator $o$ (that is, $ox=xo=o$ for all $x$), and such that for every nonidentity elements $a, b$ we have $ab=o$. A short monoid is completely characterized by how many elements it has, and is finitely generated iff it is finite (exercise - basically, there are no interesting ways to combine elements). Now suppose the class of finitely generated monoids were axiomatized by a set $\Gamma$ of first-order sentences. Let $\varphi$ be the sentence asserting that the monoid is short; do you see how to use compactness to show that $\Gamma\cup\{\varphi\}$ has an infinite model, and why that's a problem?
- *EF-games*. This was the approach you initially mentioned. Let $M_n$ be a free monoid on $n$ generators, and let $M_\infty$ be a free monoid on infinitely many generators. Then for every $n$, we can show that Duplicator has a winning strategy in the EF-game between $M_n$ and $M_\infty$ of length $n$. This shows that if $\Gamma$ is true in every $M_n$, then $\Gamma$ is true in $M_\infty$ (why?); so the class of finitely generated monoids is not axiomatizable by a set of first-order sentences.
- *Ultraproducts*. This is the nuclear solution. If you've seen the proof of compactness via ultraproducts before, then do the following: let $\mathcal{U}$ be a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, let $M_n$ be a monoid which is generated by $n$ elements but not by $n-1$ (such exist - exercise), and let $N=\prod_\mathbb{N}M_n/\mathcal{U}$ be the ultraproduct. Then it's not too hard to show that $N$ is not finitely generated; however, $N$ satisfies every sentence that all the $M_n$s satisfy by [Los' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct#.C5.81o.C5.9B.27s_theorem), so we're done.

---

You asked for more details about the EF-games approach. Well, if you understand EF-games for *graphs*, then you understand them for *relational structures* - relational structures are basically graphs, except (1) there might be more than one kind of edge relation, and (2) "edges" might connect more than one point (so really *hypergraphs* are the better analogy). But the idea is the same: alternate picking points, and at the end of the day Duplicator wins if every relation true of one tuple is true of the corresponding tuple.

We can pass from a non-relational structure, like a monoid, to a relational one, by replacing each function symbol with its *graph*. A monoid has two function symbols: a binary function symbol $*$, and a nullary function symbol (= constant symbol) $e$. We replace these with a ternary relation symbol $R_*$ and a unary relation symbol $U_e$, and consider the corresponding axioms:

- $U_e$ holds of exactly one element, and for all $a, b$ there is exactly one $c$ such that $R_*(a, b, c)$ (we interpret "$U_e(x)$" as meaning "$x$ is $e$," and interpret "$R_*(a, b, c)$" as "$a*b=c$").
- The function represented by $R_*$ is associative: $$\forall a, b, x, y, z[(R(a, b, x)\wedge R(b, c, y))\implies (R(x, c, z)\iff R(a, y, z))].$$
- The element named by $U_e$ is the identity of the function represented by $R_*$: $$\forall x(U_e(x)\implies \forall y(R(x, y, y)\wedge R(y, x, y)).$$

And any monoid $M$ can be turned into a structure in this relational language (call it a "relational monoid") $M_{rel}$ as follows:

- $M$ and $M_{rel}$ have the same underlying set.
- $U_e^{M_{rel}}=\{e^M\}$.
- $R_*^{M_{rel}}=\{(x, y, z): (x*y=z)^M\}$.

Now we can play an EF-game as usual between two relational monoids, $M_{rel}$ and $N_{rel}$. And it's not hard to show that $$M_{rel}\equiv N_{rel}\iff M\equiv N,$$ so we're actually studying the same thing.

Ebbinghaus-Flum-Thomas do something slightly different - they explicitly define EF-games on non-relational structures. But I find that slightly more complicated than passing to the relational versions.

Comment: Help me please finish it problem. When it comes to compactness theorem it is also ok, I also used it.   As I mentioned, only with graph, here it is difficult to think for me. I will think about it, but in two hours and I give you a sign about my progress.

Comment: @HaskellFun Start with the first part first. Can you find a set of sentences true in exactly the non-finitely-generated modules? (HINT: first try to find a set of sentences true in exactly the modules not generated by *one* element . . .)

Comment: You'll then want to show that every finite subset of this set of sentences has a finitely generated model.

Comment: I edited my first post and tried to use compactness theorem. Check it please

Comment: @Noah: the question is about monoids not modules. I may be missing something obvious, but I can't see how to use your hints to solve the OP's question.

Comment: @RobArthan what do you think about my solution - after edition in my first post.

Comment: @HaskellFun: if $A$ means the whole monoid, then your axioms about the $c_i$ aren't consistent since we must have $\epsilon \circ c_i = c_i$. If you are adding a predicate for membership of a submonoid $A$ to the signature, then you need to say more.

Comment: @RobArthan ok, I must add formula that $\forall_i c_i\circ \epsilon = \epsilon\circ c_i =c_i$. And something else to make this solution fully correct ?

Comment: Adding axioms won't make an inconsistent system consistent. I see now that $A$ was the set of generators in the example you were given. $A$ shouldn't appear in the solution. I don't see how to solve the problem myself at the moment. I will give it some thought.

Comment: tell me - my solution is ok?

Comment: When it comes to games - the problem is that I can't deal with gicing game. My problem is that I was using only game on graphs- monoids are blocker... Be more precisely, please

Comment: @NoahSchweber thanks you very much. When it comes to game it is sufficient to duplicator always copy move of player I. Since there are $n$ rounds and $n$ genarators in finite monoids duplicator can copy always.

Comment: I said I'd think about it and I did, but Noah produced his very nice answer while I was thinking $\ddot{\smile}$. For the record, a more familiar alternative to the "short monoids" would be abelian groups such that every element has the same finite order, e.g., $2$. As with the short monoids, you can then write down a sentence $\phi_n$ that says that no set of $n$ elements generates the group, and then get a contradiction via compactness to the existence of a set of axioms that characterises the finite structures.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you did say: *EDIT THE LAST: Haha, wow, we missed the easy solution*.
Can you show it ?

Comment: @HaskellFun I did show it - it's the "two hints" following that line. Do you see the solution I'm getting at?

Comment: @NoahSchweber did you mean: When it comes to size I think that $2^{\kappa}$, yeah ?

Comment: @HaskellFun No, it's actually much less than that - for a warmup, what's the cardinality of the set of finite binary strings? What about finite strings of natural numbers?

Comment: "What about finite strings of natural numbers?"
It depends on length of finite strings. What is maximal length ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Arbitrary finite length - I mean the set of **all** finite strings of natural numbers. (And actually, no it doesn't - the set of strings of natural numbers of length 2 is exactly the same size as the set of strings of natural numbers of length 17 . . .)

Comment: when you have lenght $17$ then $\aleph_0^{17}=\aleph_0$

Comment: @HaskellFun Indeed - and in general, for each $n$ the set of strings of naturals of length $n$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$. So what can you say about the set of all finite strings of natural numbers?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I know: countable sum of countable sets is countable :)  So answer is $\aleph_0$

Comment: @HaskellFun Yup. So, now: what can you say about the cardinality of any finitely generated monoid (or group, or ring, or . . . basically any type of structure in a countabl language)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Hmm, by analogous the same thing. My language was countable ($\mathbb{N}$). So using the fact about countable sum countable sets also cardinality of finitely generated monoid is countable.

Comment: @HaskellFun Yup! So if the class of finitely generated monoids were axiomatizable by a theory $T$, then $T$ would have infinite models (since there are infinite, finitely-generated monoids - exercise), but no uncountable models; do you see why that violates compactness?

Comment: No, I can't. After all, it violates Skolem-Lowenheim theorem. I mean that we have countable models, but no for example $\mathfrak{c}$

Comment: @HaskellFun It does violate the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, specifically the upwards direction - *but that's a consequence of Compactness*! Remember that the way upwards LS is proved is by taking your theory with infinite models, and adding $\kappa$-many constants to the language and axioms saying that those constants are distinct. By compactness, this has a model, and clearly any model has size at most $\kappa$. So while this is part of the LS theorem, it's important to remember that - unlike the downwards version - this is really a compactness theorem corollary.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Allright, so to sum up:  Analogy between strings and monoids based on two analogies:  (1) finite strings <----> finite number of generators.    (2) length of string  <----> number of generators generating some element.   yeah ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Yup. In particular, each element of the free monoid generated by $X$ is an equivalence class of finite strings of elements of $X$; so the cardinality of that monoid is $X^{<\omega}$ (this is notation for "$X\cup X^2\cup X^3 \cup .  . .$" and is different from $X^\omega$) - that is, $\aleph_0$ if $X$ is finite and $\vert X\vert$ if $X$ is infinite.