# A formula that expresses a finite graph is connected in FO.

Tags: first-order-logic

Write a such senetence $\phi$ in the first order logic that:
$$G \models \phi \text{ iff } G \text{ is connected}  $$

We consider only **finite** graphs. When it comes to infinite graphs it is obvious that FO cannot express that fact.

$$\forall p_1 \, \forall p_2 \, p_1 \neq p_2 \implies \exists n \, \exists p_2 \, \cdots \, \exists p_{n-1} \bigwedge_{1 \le i < n} e(p_i, p_{i+1})$$

Is correct? Why, why not?

Comment: In FOL you cannot quantify on the "lenght" of a formula ($\exists n$)...

Comment: I think that the class of *finite connected graphs* is not axiomatizable in FOL...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, but why, I was learnt that a formula must be of finite length but the length of my formula is finite because a graph is finite.

Comment: As Mauro stated, the length of your formula "varies with $n$", which shows that it's not a real formula. Moreover,  assume you have such a formula $\phi$. Then by an easy compactness argument, it's obvious that there will be infinite graphs that satisfy $\phi$, so again as Mauro stated, the class of finite connected graphs is not axiomatizable in FOL.

Comment: @Max, I agree that the class of finite graphs is not axiomatizable. But, I cannot see how do you get it from the compacntess argument. After all, compactness is expressed for set of sentences, not for models ( graphs are models in fact).

Comment: It's well known that if a theory (necessarily consistant with what follows) has arbitrarily large finite models, then it must have an infinite model. Compactness is enough, as you can just consider constant symbols $\{c_n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and add to your theory the axioms $c_n \neq c_m$ whenever $n\neq m$, which gives you a finitely satisfiable theory, and therefore a satisfiable theory. A model of this theory is a model of the previous one, and must be infinite.

Comment: @Max, I don't understand, please explain:
"you can just consider constant symbols $\{c_n,n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and add to your theory". Why do you take infinitely many constans while you have only finite universum ( after all, constants have to point to elements from universum). What do you mean by "add to **your** theory". I agree that it is finitely satisfable. But, I cannot see how do you know that it implies that infinite model satisfies our sentence ( theory).

Comment: Let's do it generally. Let $T$ be a consistant theory expressed in the language $L$. Assume $T$ has finite models of arbitrarily large size. Then consider the language $L'$ to which you've added different constant symbols $\{c_n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, which we can assume weren't in $L$. Then consider the theory $T^*$ expressed in $L'$ that consists of the theory $T$ + the axioms $c_n \neq c_m$ for $n\neq m$. Then, according to our assumption, $T^*$ is finitely satisfiable (is that what you have trouble seeing ?). Therefore, through compactness, $T^*$ is satisfiable.

Comment: I let you see how that's enough to show that $T$ has an infinite model

Comment: "Assume T has finite models of arbitrarily large size." Now, I cannot see why it is necessary. "let you see how that's enough to show that T has an infinite model " Probably it is connected with my the first question. I guess that the first one implies that it is possible to get infinite universum for $T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made some basic errors. The question is whether or not the following holds:

> There is a **single** first-order sentence $φ$ **in the language of graphs** such that every finite graph $G$ satisfies $φ$ iff $G$ is connected.

You **cannot** create $φ$ **after** being given $G$. Rather you must write one $φ$ down that works for **every** finite graph $G$. Secondly, quantifiers are interpreted (in any structure) to quantify over all objects in that structure, so you cannot quantify over natural numbers. Thirdly, you cannot have "$\cdots$" anywhere in your formula. In general "$\cdots$" is forbidden in any rigorous mathematics; if you cannot express it without ellipsis then it is not rigorous.

After you understand the above, then you can try your best to construct a desired $φ$, to get a feel for why it is impossible. Then carefully study the proof of the compactness theorem to see why. And you may wish to try the four problems in [this question and the two answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2000467/21820).